# Namespace not bound issue

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am new to Spring Integration and XML. I have created the following configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springProject.app"/>
<int:channel id="input"/>
<int:channel id="output">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>


<int:service-activator input-channel="input"
                       output-channel="output"
                       ref="messageHandler"/>
</beans>
```

However the IDE gives me the error, telling me that the "the namespace 'int' is not bound". Does anybody know where the error may be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the integration xmlns is bound to the prefix si, change this to int.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
```

**Notice the change in the fourth line**

Alternatively you could change all of the tags prefixed with `int` to `si`, such as:

```
<si:channel id="input"/>
<si:channel id="output">
    <si:queue capacity="10"/>
</si:channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add next text in beans tag 
*xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"* 
,and save the xml file.